# Изменить тег H2 на H1 Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Суть задачи такова:

Тема создана с помощью фреймворка и в форме слайдера Caption прописан тег H2, нужно его перезаписать на H1, возможно даже через functions.php

Можно поменять и в шаблоне вывода, но после обновления темы это изменение слетит и снова станет H2

Может фильтр какой-то...

Comment: создавайте дочернюю тему, на них обновления основной не распространяются

Comment: дочерние не вариант, есть еще предложения?

Comment: задействуй JS, он вступает в игру уже после генерации тегов. Ищи нужный и заменяй.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я уже вчера так и сделал